# Wordpress post query by author

Tags: wordpress

I want a post list by author in page. I used author post will be dynamic in each page. I used the code below.

```
<ul>
<?php
global $post;
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 3, 'post_type'=> 'post', 'author_name' => 'ppm' );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>

    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>

<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Please look on author_name array, I want post show for ppm user. Now I am going to do as dynamic. I want to get author name from page's custom field. Like

```
<?php $author_name = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'author_name', true); ?>
<ul>
<?php
global $post;
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 3, 'post_type'=> 'post', 'author_name' => '$author_name' );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>

    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>

<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

But, the code is not working. How can I get author name from page's custom field? Can anyone help?

Sorry for weak English.

Comment: you cannot get the `$post->ID` outside the loop.

Comment: see the code http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/36135/how-can-i-list-posts-by-author thanks,

Comment: I tried inside the loop, still not working.

Comment: your post in add author name using custom meta? and you can display post using custom meta ya user roll?

Comment: I have a page for author profile. I create that page manyaly. I just want the author name in array will pull down from page's custom field. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working for me. Thanks Sarim Khan for this solutions.

```
<ul>
<?php
global $post;
$author_name = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'author_name', true);
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 3, 'post_type'=> 'post', 'author_name' => $author_name );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>

    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>

<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php while (have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php $author_name = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'author_name', true); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>


<?php
        $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 3, 'post_type'=> 'post','meta_key'=>'author_name','meta_value'=>$author_name);
        query_posts($args);  
?>

<ul>
<?php while (have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
```